# PostgreSQL: Slow performance of user-defined function

Tags: sql, postgresql

My function named stat() reads from 2 tables on PostgreSQL 11.

Table T has ~1,000,000 rows, the table D has ~3,000 rows.

My function stat() runs 1.5 secs and it is slow for my use-case:

```
select * from stat('2019-01-01', '2019-10-01','UTC');
```

To improve performance I tried to create different indexes (code below), but it did not help.

I was able to improve performance when I put the hardcoded numbers '2019-01-01', '2019-10-01' instead time_start and time_end in the body of stat().

In this case it runs 0.5 sec. But this is not the solution.

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  time TIMESTAMP WITH TIME zone NOT NULL,
  ext_id INTEGER
); 

CREATE TABLE D(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  time TIMESTAMP WITH TIME zone NOT NULL,
  ext_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX t_time_idx ON T(time);
CREATE INDEX d_time_idx ON D(time);
CREATE INDEX t_ext_idx ON T(ext_id);
CREATE INDEX d_ext_idx ON D(ext_id);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION stat(time_start varchar, time_end varchar, tz varchar)
RETURNS TABLE (result float)
AS $$
DECLARE
   time_points INTEGER;
   capacity INTEGER;
BEGIN
   time_points := 1000; 
   capacity := 12;
RETURN QUERY
SELECT (total::float / (capacity * time_points))::float  as result
FROM (
   SELECT count(*)::float AS total FROM T
   INNER JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT ext _id, name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ext_id ORDER BY time desc) AS rk
           FROM D WHERE time at time zone tz < time_end::timestamp
       ) InB WHERE rk = 1
   ) D_INFO
   ON T.ext_id = D_INFO.ext_id
   WHERE T.time at time zone tz between time_start::timestamp and time_end::timestamp
     ) B;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Usage:

```
select * from stat('2019-01-01', '2019-10-01','UTC');  --> takes 1.5 sec, too slow
```

What I tried:

```
ANALYZE T;
ANALYZE D;
```

I created different indexes for T and D tables

```
CREATE INDEX covering_t_time_ext_idx ON t(ext_id) INCLUDE (time);
CREATE INDEX t_time_ext_idx ON T(time) INCLUDE (ext_id);
CREATE INDEX t_time_ext_multicolumn_idx ON t(time, ext_id);
CREATE INDEX t_time_ext_multicolumn2_idx ON t(ext_id, time);
```

but it did not help to improve performance.

Comment: Add [`auto_explain`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auto-explain.html) to `shared_preload_libraries`, set `auto_explain.log_min_duration = 500` and `auto_explain.log_analyze`, `auto_explain.log_buffers` and `auto_explain.log_nested_statements` to `on` and run the function. Then you'll get the execution plan of the slow execution in the log file. Please add that to the question.

Answer (score 0):

function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION stat(time_start varchar, time_end varchar, tz varchar)
RETURNS TABLE (result float)
AS $$
DECLARE
   time_points INTEGER;
   capacity INTEGER;
BEGIN
   time_points := 1000; 
   capacity := 12;
RETURN QUERY
SELECT (total::float / (capacity * time_points))::float  as result
FROM (
   SELECT count(*)::float AS total 
   FROM T
   WHERE T.time at time zone tz between time_start::timestamp and time_end::timestamp
   AND EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM D 
      WHERE D.ext_id = T.ext_id
      AND D.time at time zone tz < time_end::timestamp
   )
) B;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by casting the input parameters:

```
(time_start varchar, time_end varchar)
```

into intermediate variables with type timestamp:

```
 DECLARE
    start_time timestamp;
    end_time timestamp;

 BEGIN
    start_time := time_start::timestamp;
    end_time   := time_end::timestamp;
```

and using these intermediate variables in the SQL instead doing this casting in SQL.